# Why don't I have permission to create this directory / file? Permissions on Debian 11 Linux

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I thought I understood Linux permissions, but alas... why don't I have permissions here?

I'm part of the `www-data` group:

```
docker@docker01:/home/docker$ id
uid=1002(docker) gid=998(docker) groups=998(docker),33(www-data)
```

The parent directory is user/group `www-data`, and the group has `rwx`:

```
docker@docker01:/home/docker$ ls -lh /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x 768 www-data www-data 20K Jun  1 08:01 private
drwxrwxr-x 777 www-data www-data 20K Jun  5 20:55 public
```

But when I try to create a new subdirectory, I get a permissions error:

```
docker@docker01:/home/docker$ mkdir /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public/803y9xcn

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public/803y9xcn’: Permission denied
```

What am I missing here...?

Comment: Does it work when creating the folder as root?

Comment: Yes, I can create folders in that directory as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are `rwxrwxr-x` which mean `rwx` for owner ("read-write-execute"), `rwx` for group, `r-x` for others.

For directories, "read" flag (`r`) means "get a directory listing", "write" (`w`) means "create/delete/rename objects" in that directory, and "execute" (`x`) is "enter" (cd) into that directory.

Changes (`w`) are permitted only for owner or owner-group. You're `docker` and you aren't the owner which is `www-data`. Likely `docker` doesn't belong to the `www-data` group, so you are one of those "others", who are not permitted to write.

This could be solved:

- by using POSIX ACL to add permissions specifically for the `docker` user or group it belongs to;
- by adding `docker` into `www-data` group;
- by changing permissions to be world-writable.

Options are presented in the order of decreasing security (as opposed to increased ease of implementation). In addition, two lower options have a caveat: newly created objects will be owned by `docker` and now `www-data` won't have control over them; it could be it will not able to delete them or even read, that depends on what permissions objects are created with. It's messy and I suggest to not do that. I'd explain the POSIX ACL path:

```
setfacl -m user:docker:rwx /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public
setfacl -m default:user:docker:rwx /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public
setfacl -m default:user:www-data:rwx /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public
setfacl -m default:group:www-data:rwx /var/www/userdata02.example.com/html/public
```

Even in first case objects will be owned by creator (`docker`), but you can have a "default" ACL which will be applied to all new objects and nested to subdirectories, so you can force all new object to have full permissions for `www-data`. This is what three lower lines are for.

Or, you can create a special group for such object and instead of giving permissions to `user:docker` give them to `group:that_group`. Depending on what you are going to do in Docker, it might make your life easier later.

Comment: If you look at my question, the `docker` user _is_ part of the `www-data` group already.

Comment: Yes, I missed that somehow. Sorry. Are you sure there is no object in that directory with the name you are going to create? Also, any chances you hit an AppArmor denial? Show `cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled`; look for `DENIED` in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: So this returns `Y`: `/sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled`  I don't see anything in `syslog` though.